# raise UnknownBackendException embed_video.backends.UnknownBackendException

Tags: django

I am making my website using django-embed-video package of django.

Since I'm thinking about starting with a configuration that is as simple as possible, I made a website only index.html, then I installed django-embed-video.
Then I added following code base on the tutorial, however, it doesn't display youtube video and display following error message.

My environment is as follows.
django 2.0
python 3.6
django-embed-video 1.1.2

error message

```
Backend wasn't recognised (``)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\django_project\virtualenv2\lib\site-　 
packages\embed_video\templatetags\embed_video_tags.py", line 111, in render
return self.embed(url, size, context=context, **options)
File "F:\django_project\virtualenv2\lib\site- 
packages\embed_video\templatetags\embed_video_tags.py", line 185, in embed
backend = cls.get_backend(url, context=context, **options)
File "F:\django_project\virtualenv2\lib\site- 
packages\embed_video\templatetags\embed_video_tags.py", line 164, in 
get_backend
else detect_backend(str(backend_or_url))
File "F:\django_project\virtualenv2\lib\site- 
packages\embed_video\backends.py", line 62, in detect_backend
raise UnknownBackendException
embed_video.backends.UnknownBackendException
```

stteings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'embed_video',
 ]
```

It added 'django.template.context_processors.request' by default in 'context_processors' of TEMPLATES.

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
name = models.CharField('Video name', max_length=100, null=True)
video = models.URLField()  # same like models.URLField()
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
return render(request, 'app/index.html')
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from embed_video.admin import AdminVideoMixin
from .models import Item

class MyModelAdmin(AdminVideoMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
pass

admin.site.register(Item, MyModelAdmin)
```

Custom backends have not made anything.
What is the cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to find a solution.
view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Item

def index(request):
   allItems= Item.objects.all()
   context= {'allitems': allItems}
   return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

In my example, it was solved by modifying as above.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same issue. i looked around and they say its a bug because you have an empty string. if you have figured it out, please let me know. i ll continue looking around. if i found a solution, i ll post it here too.

Comment: Thank you comment.I could find a solution as above. Please check it.

Comment: Ok, i kinda teared down the whole thing and followed the example here https://github.com/jazzband/django-embed-video/tree/master/example_project   

and it worked. however i am facing another issue with the proxy timing out when its getting the video thumbnail but hey its working. try to follow the example closely and hopefully it will work with you too.

Answer (score 0):

in your case just do this in your templates files

```
{% for items in allItems %}
  {% video items.video as my_video %}
    URL: {{ my_video.url }}
    Thumbnail: {{ my_video.thumbnail }}
    Backend: {{ my_video.backend }}
  {% endvideo %}
{% endfor %}
```

and replace URLFIELD by EmbedVideoField()