# How to display the youtube url stored in django database in template

Tags: python, django

**here is the stuff i have done and i am getting error of no videos yet**

I have been following **django-embed-video** tutorial by **jazzband** and everything is setup and i uploaded url in my database ,but when running the database no any videos is displaying in my template **.It's throwing error**

```
 file "\env\lib\site-packages\embed_video\templatetags\embed_video_tags.py", 
  line 196, in embedbackend = cls.get_backend(url, context=context, **options)
  
File "\env\lib\site-packages\embed_video\templatetags\embed_video_tags.py", 
   line 174, in get_backend else detect_backend(str(backend_or_url))

  File "\env\lib\site-packages\embed_video\backends.py", line 64, in detect_backend
    raise UnknownBackendException embed_video.backends.UnknownBackendException
```

*here is /app/models.py*

```
class youtube(models.Model):
video = EmbedVideoField(default="")
def __str__(self):
    return self.video
```

/app/views.py

```
  from .models import youtube
    def display_video(request):
    videos = youtube.objects.all()
    context = {'video': videos}
    return render (request, 'library.html', context)
```

library.html

```
{% load embed_video_tags %}
{% video item.video 'small' %}
{% block content %}
{% if videos %}
    {% for v in videos %}
    {{ v.video }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <p>No videos yet</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

/myproject/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'embed_video',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['template'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                **'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',**
             

            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: hi, have a look at this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539335/raise-unknownbackendexception-embed-video-backends-unknownbackendexception

Comment: Hello @ansuman thanks for your time.I have already gone through this. and i have same **admin.py **<h1>
from django.contrib import admin from embed_video.admin import AdminVideoMixin from .models import Item class MyModelAdmin(AdminVideoMixin, admin.ModelAdmin): pass admin.site.register(Item, MyModelAdmin)<h2>

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `{% video item.video 'small' %}`
to `{% video youtube.video 'small' %}`